# Discontinuity in the charging of an inductor

Tags: inductor, power-electronics, non-linear

I have a buck converter without the output capacitor connected so I would able to see the current of the inductor by the voltage at the load.

I'm using a IR2110 to drive the mosfet.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFUsGn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have this response:

[image]

At the beginning of the cycle there are some peaks those what worse when I increase the load.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you use any integrated circuits?Also,could you please attach the schematics of the circuit

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: A schematic would be useful.

Comment: try adding some gate resistance. maybe 10 ohms.

Comment: Jasen, sorry, but it's a bad idea. Gate current is controlled by the driver (or he has to change the driver). The trace to the gate must be shortest possible. And mosfet's source must be close to the driver, so the mesh will be smallest possible

Comment: @GregoryKornblum No the driver IR2110 has to have a gate resistor at output. Preferably two of them Ron and Roff combined between them with a diode.  This schematics lacks of full information, the power supply and connecton of the gate driver and the input control of it.

Answer (score 2):

How are you measuring the current ? A sense resistor, or a current clamp ?

Small amounts of capacitive coupling to your current sense R, or poor common-mode rejection in your scope will cause this type of waveform.

Also, if the inductor is relatively large (physically), it is possible there is some capacitance between the ends of the windings -- you don't have a pure inductance -- and so the total current *can* have discontinuities.

(I see your schematic now).

Check how your scopes' probe is grounded -- it should be just at the R also. In addition, sometimes scopes can pickup common-mode signals -- try to connect *both* the probe and the ground clip *together* to the bottom of the R -- you should see no signal, but anything you do see is in indication of this.

What diode are you using -- if it is not a fast one, reverse recovery current will actually cause large transient currents and noise spikes in the circuit.

Comment: I have tried with 2 inductors, one is about 3 cm of diameter, the other one about 5cm. Ok I've the circuit in a breadboard that may may be causing the capacitance? the switching frequency is 100 kHz. I'm just measuring the voltage at the R.

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez -- I agree that much of this is likely measurement-related error rather than real circuit voltages. I was getting similar results on a switcher circuit using my standard witch's hat clip and ground lead on my scope probe. I built up a 12" BNC terminated RG-174 coax cable soldered directly to the current sense resistor and now my scope trace is clean as a whistle. There's still some subtle ringing at the bottom, but now I believe I'm looking at the real signal rather than the ringing of an inadvertent tank circuit formed by my scope probe :)

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez -- also, forgot to mention, a 50 ohm input impedance to the scope. That's very important. I use an external 50 ohm pass-through connector because my scope doesn't have a 50 ohm setting. This changes the current sense resistor value slightly; in my case I'm using a 1 ohm resistor so it doesn't mean much, but with your 18 ohm resistor you may want to take it into account.

Comment: Be careful using a 50 ohm load -- likely it can't take the power that 17 V could deliver.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like electromagnetic interference. I would bet on switching node voltage capacitively coupled to your probe, but it can also be current pulse from the input capacitor (hope you have it) with magnetic flux. You should anyway use best possible layout and shortest ground for your probe, and even then you will still have a little interference.

By the way, it's a really nice illustration for dc/dc beginners. What happens when you don't make things right. Pay attention, although you have some switching frequency there, the interference is in much higher range.